# Choosing table structure for MSSQL Server to render GeoSpatial Data on OpenLayers Map?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, sql-server-spatial

I have billions of public data sets.
I created MSSQL Database with the following table Structure:

```
ID:nvarchar,
Name:nvarchar,
Latitude:nvarchar,
Longitude:nvarchar,
Geometry:geometry
```

To represent on Openlayer map I'm going to store data and to render storing data on Map for that I'm going to use GeoServer MSSQL DataStore.

What should my table structure be like so that I will not get any performance issues?

Comment: provided you have a spatial index on the geometry column you should be fine with that one - the structure of your table is pretty much irrelevant to speed, for faster access switch to PostGIS.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/12930/6229